# Get variables from the environment in go?

Tags: go, environment

I have data set in the environment variable GOPATH and I would like to programatically extract this data in my program. I would prefer to fetch all the ENV variables as a `map[string]interface{}`. This is because I want to integrate the ENV values with my JSON config witch I currently fetch like so.

```
 var data map[string]interface{}

 file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(configFilePath)
 if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
 }
 err = json.Unmarshal(file, &data)
 if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
 }
```

Comment: I found this [os.Environ()] (http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Environ) which seems to do the job of finding the env variables but Im still having problems with restructuring the data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[os.Environ()](http://godoc.org/os#Environ) returns the strings representing the environment in the form "key=value". To create a map, iterate through the strings, split on "=" and set the map entry.

```
m := make(map[string]string)
for _, e := range os.Environ() {
    if i := strings.Index(e, "="); i >= 0 {
        m[e[:i]] = e[i+1:]
    }
}
```

Comment: I found something similar on my own but I haven't had time to post it yet so thanks!