# Is it possible to get the environment vars set using os.Setenv in Golang using a debugger?

Tags: go, debugging, environment-variables

This is the equivalent of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32917033/how-to-get-environment-of-a-program-while-debugging-it-in-gdb), but for Golang.

The answer describes using `call getenv("<Var_Name>");` inside `gdb`, but that does not work for Go applications.

**Is it possible to get the updated values of env variables inside a Golang process from a debugger?**

For the purposes of this question, please assume there's no source access so I cannot modify the source code to simply print the values when I want.
Instead, I am trying to observe the changes to env variable values using a debugger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get variables from the environment in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293961/get-variables-from-the-environment-in-go)

Comment: @Inian For this question, please assume I cannot modify and rebuild the application. I'm trying to read the updated env vars from outside the process, or with a debugger.

Comment: Are you attaching a debugger for a Go program and basically read its environment?

Comment: That's correct. But the program seems to update its own environment after it starts so I want the updated environment. Otherwise I could just use `/proc/PID/environ`.

Comment: Well, I guess one way would be to log the environment values at certain points in your code. For example fmt.Println(os.Getenv("")). Another, depending on your debugger, for example in Goland you have evaluate expression. Where you can type os.Getenv("yourvalue") and should bring back the result.

Comment: @pavleprica I think you missed the note about the assumption that there's no source code access.

Comment: Not using `gdb` but it should work if you use [Delve](https://github.com/go-delve/delve). I'm not writing this as an answer because I've never used Delve but https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/119 makes it look like what you're trying to do should work in that debugger.

Comment: My bad there. It seems I have, even though I read it. My apologies. To understand better the problem, I presume you just attach the debugger, to some process. Do you have any control as an input that would pause or somehow give you more "control" over the flow?

Comment: I can send requests to the process which cause changes to the env vars, but I'm not sure if that's what you mean by "control" over the flow.